# RequestEncoding settings on azure function app

Tags: .net, azure, .net-core, azure-functions, azure-functions-isolated

I have an Azure function app with a common trigger signature like this

```
public static async Task<IActionResult> RunAsync(
     [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
     ILogger log)
```

The request body "req.Body" doesn't have utf-8 encoding. For this particular application I need this specific encoding. How do I achieve this, I am using the azure function isolated process. In regular asp.net app I believe there is a globalization setting for this, if am not mistaken is like this.

```
<system.web>  
  <globalization   
    requestEncoding="utf-8"  
    responseEncoding="utf-8"/>  
</system.web>
```

How do I achive the same thing for the function app.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I was able to encode the data from request body.

I am using `.NET 8 Isolated process`

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Text;

namespace FunctionApp5
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Function1> _logger;

        public Function1(ILogger<Function1> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [Function("Function1")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequest req)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(req.Body))
            {
                string requestBody = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();

                // Decode the bytes using UTF-8 encoding
                requestBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestBody));

                return new OkObjectResult($"Welcome to Azure Functions!\n decoded request body: {requestBody}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## `INPUT`:

```
Hello Vivek, encoding data
```

## `OUTPUT`:

```
Functions:

        Function1: [GET,POST] http://localhost:7158/api/Function1

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-02-23T04:05:07.381Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000116B5F66'.
[2024-02-23T04:05:23.996Z] Executing 'Functions.Function1' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=bc6d094e-48f5-4de7-b9e9-d26e884e19f6)
[2024-02-23T04:05:24.744Z] C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.
[2024-02-23T04:05:24.750Z] Executing OkObjectResult, writing value of type 'System.String'.
[2024-02-23T04:05:24.962Z] Executed 'Functions.Function1' (Succeeded, Id=bc6d094e-48f5-4de7-b9e9-d26e884e19f6, Duration=1037ms)
```

[image]

```
Welcome to Azure Functions!
 decoded request body: Hello Vivek, encoding data
```

[image]

Comment: Yes thank you that is definetely an option, but in my scenario the req.Body stream needs to be passed as an argument to a third party module, so I have no control of how the stream is read on their end. I know I can always make a copy of the Stream with whatever encoding I want but that seemed a bit hacky. I was looking for a more elegant solution at the app configuration level. But in the absence of that I will definitely use something like this. Thanks

Comment: @user2503480 AFAIK, there is no direct configuration at the app level to enforce `utf-8` encoding for request bodies in Azure Functions.